# How to reformat file with sed/vim?

Tags: csv, vim, sed

I have a `.csv` file that looks like this.

```
atomnum,atominfo,metric
238,A-30-CYS-SG,53.7723
889,A-115-CYS-SG,46.2914
724,A-94-CYS-SG,44.6405
48,A-6-CYS-SG,37.2108
630,A-80-CYS-SG,29.574
513,A-64-CYS-SG,23.1925
981,A-127-CYS-SG,19.8903
325,A-41-GLN-OE1,17.6205
601,A-76-CYS-SG,17.5079
```

I want to change it like this:

```
atomnum,atominfo,metric
238,C30-SG,53.7723
889,C115-SG,46.2914
724,C94-SG,44.6405
48,C6-SG,37.2108
630,C80-SG,29.574
513,C64-SG,23.1925
981,C127-SG,19.8903
325,Q41-OE1,17.6205
601,C76-SG,17.5079
```

The part between the commas is an atom identifier: where A-30-CYS-SG is the gamma sulfur of the residue 30, which is a cysteine, in chain A. Residues can be represented with three letters or just one (Table here https://www.iupac.org/publications/pac-2007/1972/pdf/3104x0639.pdf). Basically, I just want to a) change the three letter code to the one letter code, b) remove the chain id (A in this case) and c) put the residue number next to the one letter code.

I've tried matching the patterns between the commas within vim. Something like `s%:\(-\d\+\-\)\(\u\+\):\2\1:g` gives me c) i.e. (`ACYS-30--SG`). I do not know how to do a) with vim. I know how to do it with sed and an input file with all the substitute commands in it. But then maybe is better to do all the work with sed... I am asking if is it possible to do a) on vim?

Thanks

Comment: If you don't describe what the change is, exactly, people have to guess based on input and output. Also, your question would probably be better received if you showed what you tried and how it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`, `paste`, `cut`, & `bash`, given input *atoms.csv*:

```
paste -d, <(cut -d, -f1 atoms.csv) \
          <(cut -d, -f2 atoms.csv | sed 's/.-//
                                         s/\(.*\)-\([A-Z]\{3\}\)-/\2\1-/
                                         s/^ALA/A/
                                         s/^ARG/R/
                                         s/^ASN/N/
                                         s/^ASP/D/
                                         s/^CYS/C/
                                         s/^GLU/E/
                                         s/^GLN/Q/
                                         s/^GLY/G/
                                         s/^HIS/H/
                                         s/^ILE/I/
                                         s/^LEU/L/
                                         s/^LYS/K/
                                         s/^MET/M/
                                         s/^PHE/F/
                                         s/^PRO/P/
                                         s/^SER/S/
                                         s/^THR/T/
                                         s/^TRP/W/
                                         s/^TYR/Y/
                                         s/^VAL/V/') \
          <(cut -d, -f3 atoms.csv)
```

Output:

```
atomnum,atominfo,metric
238,C30-SG,53.7723
889,C115-SG,46.2914
724,C94-SG,44.6405
48,C6-SG,37.2108
630,C80-SG,29.574
513,C64-SG,23.1925
981,C127-SG,19.8903
325,Q41-OE1,17.6205
601,C76-SG,17.5079
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1b;s/$/\n:ALAA:ARGR:ASNN:ASPD:CYSC:GLUE:GLNQ:GLYG:HISH:ILEI:LEUL:LYSK:METM:PHEF:PROP:SERS:THRT:TRPW:TYRY:VALV/;s/,A-([0-9]+)-(...)(.*)\n.*:\2(.).*/,\4\1\3/' file
```

Append a lookup table to each line and use pattern matching to substitute a 3 letter code (and integer value) for a 1 letter code. The lookup key is a colon, followed by the 3 letter key, followed by the 1 letter code.

Comment: Line 2 of the output was the lookup table itself, which departs from the spec.  Fixed...

Comment: Works, except that the lookup key appears randomly in the output.

Comment: @murpholinox if the lookup table appears randomly in the output, that would suggest that the lookup table is incomplete and that there is a key or keys not accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to do it in sed why not leverage that knowledge and simply call out from Vim?

```
:%!sed -e '<your sed script>'
```

Once you done that and it works you can pop it in a Vim function.

```
functioni Transform()
    your sed command
endfunction
```

and then just use

```
:call Transform()
```

which you can map to a key.

Simples!

Comment: Glad to know that. I actually did it with sed, but just now I accidentally remove the input file. Thanks